# Prime Number Patterns

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Andrew Granville, Prime Number Patterns, page $282$. The fourth line.
What is the difference between column and vertical line ? 
[image]

Comment: A cube has dimension $3$. Three mutually orthogonal directions. Triples in one direction are called rows, in the next columns, and the last "vertical lines". Thus Granville pictures rows and columns horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $3$-by-$3$-by-$3$

It is three dimensional, so a column (x), row (y), and vertical line (z)